# UseHTML property in XAxisTitle or YAxisTitle

Tags: c#, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

Class **Title** of DotNet.Highcharts has property UseHtml,but I can't find the same property in class **XAxisTitle** and **YAxisTitle**.

How can I display html text(for example СН<sub>3</sub>СНО) in yaxis or xaxis title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wergeld's answer is correct,but I've found another solution.

We can extend YAxisTitle using inheritance and add property UseHtml.

```
public class YAxisTitleExtend : YAxisTitle
{
     public bool? UseHTML { get; set; }
}
```

And using YAxisTitleExtend instead of YAxisTitle.

If another not explicitly properties have appeared,we can simply add theirs to extend class.

Comment: Ah, yes. We roll our own API here as well. DNHC just seems to lag behind quite a bit from HC code. Not blaming DNHC - just saying development by the HC team is very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the API docs for HighCharts the [`xAxis`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.title) and [`yAxis`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.title) titles do not have the property to use HTML. However, it is still present:

```
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'СН<SUB>3</SUB>СНО',
        useHTML: true,
        style: {
            color: 'red'
        }
    }
}
```

The DotNet.Highcharts API only exposes items that are in the HighCharts API explicitly. This is one of the reasons we stopped using it. You could add an event in the [`chart.events.load`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load) section to set the axis title `useHTML` property:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function (event) {
            this.yAxis[0].setTitle({
                useHTML: true,
            });
        }
    }
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'СН<SUB>3</SUB>СНО'
    }
}
```

Live [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/F53AX/) of using `load` event.